# Anyone know how to add a callback to a jquery UI theme?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, customization

This is so redundant, but I have a specific element that does not need the same theme installed elsewhere. That being so, I just need to change the CSS of one of the widgets I use the Jquery UI with.

Other elements needed to be added as well into the filter, so I was hoping to be able to be create a callback in the instantiation of the autocomplete, where I could remove it's styling class, and replace it with a new one.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so I was hoping to be able to be create a callback in the
>   instantiation of the autocomplete

Yes, you can do that. Just tap into the `create` event for the widget:

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   create: function(event, ui) { ... }
});
```